Extracting questions from MCQ PDF
So what im trying to do is extract MCQ questions from a pdf. These are saved as screenshots because some questions contain formatting elements such as images and tables. So basically I need to store screenshots of questions
I tried many things with the following logic:

Find a "bold question number"
Start a screenshot a little right of that bold question number
End the screenshot a little above the bold question number
Repeat for all questions

Nothing seems to work. So im pretty much blank about this

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
